# Find files bigger than 300MB using os.walk in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have written this code to walk a directory and find files bigger than 300MB.

However, I get a lot of duplicate values and the number of duplicates varies between the files. Can anyone explain this or improve the code for me?

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\brentond\\Desktop\\Lower Thames Crossing'
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        for filename in filenames:
            if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(foldername, filename))>300000000:
                print(foldername + '\\' + filename)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to explore the subfolders yourself, [walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) does it for you.

From the doc:

> os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
>
> Generate
>   the file names in a directory tree by **walking the tree** either top-down
>   or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top
>   (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames,
>   filenames).

(emphasis mine)

So, just do:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\brentond\\Desktop\\Lower Thames Crossing'
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(foldername, filename))>300000000:
            print(foldername + '\\' + filename)
```

Comment: Hi I don't think I want the print(filenames) before the loop as I am only interested in printing the big files. I get an error with this code though. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 3, in <module>
    if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(foldername, filename))>300000000:
  File "C:\Users\brentond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\brentond\\Desktop\\Lower Thames Crossing\\PSSR\\Options Phase\

Comment: Think it's because there are zip files within zip files so the string is very long?

Comment: import os

#path = 'C:\\Users\\brentond\\Desktop\\Lower Thames Crossing'
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
        if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(foldername, filename))>300000000:
            print(foldername + '\\' + filename)

Comment: So the Error was caused by a path that was 278 characters long. By moving the files up a few levels to shorten the path string the above code now runs perfectly with no duplicates. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Skip the subfolders loop.

Walk already goes through subfolders.

Every folder will be foldername exactly once. For each folder, its immediate child files will feature in filenames, each once.

Its immediate child folders will feature in subfolders, each once. You do not need to loop over subfolders unless you want to do something to the folder directly other than check its contents.